# Querying arrays within documents in Google Firestore

Tags: node.js, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I have a document in a collection which has an array of objects as a property.

e.g.

```
Projects
   name: 'Great Project'
   members: [{id:'1', name:'rob']
```

I want to get all projects with rob as a member.

I was hoping this would work

```
collection("projects")
    .where("members.name", "array-contains", "rob")
```

...but nope.

As you can see, I'm trying to get the ID

I suppose I could use a sub collection, but then I'd have a similar issue.

What am I doing wrong!

And, is this the best way to store this data?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query currently looks for documents where the field `owners` is a map with a nested array of string `names` having `rob` in it. But in your sample document the field with array of objects is `members`. To use `array-contains` with an array of objects, you need to pass in the complete object as is:

```js
const owner = {id: '1', name: 'rob'}

const db = firebase.firestore()
const projectsCol = db.collection("projects")

const query = projectsCol.where("members", "array-contains", owner)
```

That being said, you need to know the `id` field present in the object as well.

You could move members to a sub-collection instead of an array and use [Collection Group](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries#collection-group-query) queries. The database structure would look something like:

```
projects -> {projectId} -> members -> {memberId}
```

Each document in members subcollection would be similar to:

```
{
  id: "1",
  name: "rob",
  ...otherFields
}
```

Now you can run a collection group query on "members" which will return all documents where the name is "rob" and then you can use [`DocumentReference`](https://firebase.google.com/docs/reference/node/firebase.firestore.DocumentReference) to all matches documents to get the project ID.

```js
const query = firebase.firestore().collectionGroup("members").where("name", "==", "rob")

query.get().then((snapshot) => {
  console.log(snapshot.docs.map(d => d.ref.parent.parent.id))
})
```

This should log IDs of projects where the rob is a member.

Comment: Thank you for seeing past the question typo. You were right - I needed to pass in an entire object to the array-contains clause. I had to add .get() on the end of there query to get the snapshot but otherwise all sorted, thank you.

Comment: @RobEllis yes the `get()` method is required to fetch the document. I just did it in next line for better readability. `query.get()`

Comment: If anyone wants to get the documents after retrieving the IDs as Dharmaraj shows, you can use : await db.collection("projects").where(Firestore.FieldPath.documentId(), "in", projectids).get();